# How can I make Ef Core totally ignore an object who wraps other properties inside an Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to make EfCore ignore a wrapping object similarly to the owned type concept.

How can I turn this object:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public object SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OtherItem> OtherItems { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
}

public class OtherItem
{
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

Into this object

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Aggregate Aggregate { get; set; } // This should not be mapped to the Database but only the properties
}

[Owned] // I think this is what i'm looking for
public class Aggregate
{
    public object SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OtherItem> OtherItems { get; set; }

    public void SomeUsefulFunction()
    {
        // do Something Useful on the Aggregate
    }
}
```

I would like EfCore to completely ignore the Aggregate object and threat his properties as if they were from the entity object. I thought the concept of owned entities was exactly this but I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Aggregate.OtherItems' of type 'ICollection<OtherItem>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore thi
s property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "treat (Aggregate) properties as if they were from the entity object"? In C# they'll always belong to `Aggregate` and in the database they can't possibly be mapped to `Entity` table columns because they're collections. I don't see how you picture this.

Comment: Well in this example. SomeProperty would be in the Entity Table and of course the collections would be in another table but would have a foreign key on the Entity table because the Aggregate table would simple not exists..

Comment: Maybe better to do not pollute Model and introduce DTO classes? The projection can be made via `Select`.

Comment: I'm trying to follow DDD principles with a rich domain model instead of an anemic one. I don't want to duplicate the logic in my Dtos and I also want to maintain my domain in a valid state using aggregates.

Comment: Is this a wrong approach? should I only put this logic into my dtos?

Comment: @R.Haughton what Svyatoslav Danyliv suggests is to have different set of classes (DTOs) that will be used only for configuring EF so you have desired DB structure. I suppose for retrieving aggregates you will use some form of Repository pattern. Inside Repository you can convert your DTO result from DB to Entity.
All the logic should be kept inside Entity classes.

Comment: Can only be done if `Item` and `OtherItem` are owned types as well. I'm not sure if you want that because EF will always join-in the collections when fetching Entity objects. I always find it's a fruitless operation to make an EF class model adhere to DDD. The responsibilities don't match (data layer vs domain model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public Aggregate Aggregate => new Aggregate(this);
    protected object SomeProperty { get; set; }
    protected ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    protected ICollection<OtherItem> OtherItems { get; set; }
}

public class Aggregate
{
    public object SomeProperty => _entity.SomeProperty;
    public ICollection<Item> Items => _entity.Items;
    public ICollection<OtherItem> OtherItems => _entity.OtherItems;
    
    public Aggregate(Entity entity)
    {
       _entity = entity;
    }
    public void SomeUsefulFunction()
    {
        // do Something Useful on the Aggregate
    }
}


public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Ignore(c => c.Aggregate);
    }
}
```

PS Just showing how to get, you can easly adapt it to use set too.

Comment: Looks good but the only thing I dislike is that the "Entity" has also the collections of items . We could then directly modify the items in the Entity without using the aggregate and achieving consistency while the aggregate business rules of the "UsefulFunction".

Comment: Its protected - you cant modify it outside of class. You can make 'Aggregate' properties protected if you want.

Comment: and how to for example Ignore an ICollection from Aggregate?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to check out dotnet reference architecture https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers. There Ordering service is build using DDD approach - https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Services/Ordering.
It has good examples how to model Aggregates, Domain Events (`Ordering.Domain` folder) and also repository implementation along with configuration of EF entities (`Ordering.Infrastructure` folder).

Also there're couple of solution templates available to avoid typing boilerplate code :

- https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture
- https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture

From microsoft docs :

> Applications that follow the Dependency Inversion Principle as well as the Domain-Driven Design (DDD) principles tend to arrive at a similar architecture. This architecture has gone by many names over the years. One of the first names was Hexagonal Architecture, followed by Ports-and-Adapters. More recently, it's been cited as the Onion Architecture or Clean Architecture

Comment: The question is about an EF technicality, not architecture. Don't get deluded by the word "aggrgate".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, will look into my projects where I've used Owned properties to find something useful.